# How do I group legend entries using Chartjs?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chart.js

Does [Chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/) support grouping legend entries based on some fixed attribute?  For example, say I'd like to group two legend entries and provide them a common heading 'Neuroscience'.  Is this currently supported in the library?

Attached is an image of what I'm looking to do.

[image: Example of what I'm looking to do]

Answer (score 0):

After more research, yes Chartjs provides an easy interface to customize the legend.  Each chart accepts a `legendCallback` function that takes the chart object as it's only argument and returns a html string representing the legend.

See [Chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-common-chart-configuration) docs for more info.